# Redirect https://abc.ai to https://abc.co

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, dns, cloudflare, nameservers

I have two domains in cloudflare DNS - abc.ai and abc.co

My main website is on `abc.co`
So I want to redirect the user to `https://abc.co` whoever comes to `https://abc.ai`

I tried creating a `CNAME` in `DNS` records of `abc.ai`, but it didn't work.

```
TYPE = CNAME
NAME = abc.ai
TARGET = abc.co
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: To avoid problems with HTTPS certificate names, when a visitor arrives at `abc.ai`,  configure your webserver to return an HTTP 30x [redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) to the new site. This also means you must maintain a working web server for the old domain. Apache/Nginx can be configured to do this for you on the same server.

Comment: Suggestion. You can configure Google Cloud Run to serve the old website and redirect the visitors to your new site. One benefit is very low cost. Another is that you can easily monitor how many visitors are continuing to go to your old site.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect one domain to another
If you have an alias domain that only forwards traffic to another domain, you can set up redirects directly within Cloudflare.

1. Add your alias domain (for example, previous.com) to Cloudflare.
2. Make sure that your alias domain has a proxied DNS A or CNAME record that properly resolves DNS queries. You may also want to include a record for the www subdomain.

[image]

3. Use Bulk redirects to forward traffic from your alias domain to your other domain. Select Include subdomains and Subpath matching to cover your entire alias domain (for example, [www.previous.com](http://www.previous.com) and [www.previous.com/examples](http://www.previous.com/examples)).

[image]

Source: https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/setup/manage-domains/redirect-domain/